# What does adding 2 dots to a directory do within a sys.path list?

Tags: python, path, package, sys

Looking at https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/main/samples/python/introductory_parser_samples/onnx_resnet50.py

There is this code:     `sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], ".."))` which inserts the same working directory with 2 dots to the sys.path list:

```
  ['/home/pran/Downloads/workingdirectory', 
'/home/pran/Downloads/workingdirectory/..', 
'/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6']
```

If the working directory is already in the list then I should be able to access that directory already. So what difference does the two dots make?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `..` -> parent. It adds the parent of the working directory to the path. Resolving the absolute paths happen at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It's adding the parent directory.

As a general rule of thumb `..` points to the parent of the directory.